# angularjs limitTo filter not working with odd json array

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an odd json array that I can ng-repeat just fine, but I'm having trouble limiting this list with the limitTo filter. I'm getting the json object with an http call so I can't change how the object is formed on the back-end.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="school in schoolList | limitTo:2">
        {{school.school_name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
{"0":{"school_name":"FAKE ELEMENTARY"},
 "1":{"school_name":"CENTRAL HIGH"},
 "2":{"school_name":"OAK RIDGE ELEMENTARY"},
 "3":{"school_name":"PINE MEADOW ELEMENTARY"},
 "4":{"school_name":"AMERICAN MIDDLE"},
 "5":{"school_name":"BIG SENIOR HIGH"},
 "6":{"school_name":"ST FRANCIS ELEMENTARY SCHOOL"}
```

**Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu7rZ/101/)**

My first thought is that I could somehow use $index but I haven't had any luck thus far. Any help would be appreciated. I apologize in advanced if this has already been answered but I've been searching for a few days without finding anything helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the angular source the first check is:

```
if (!isArray(input) && !isString(input)) return input;
```

So you will have to convert that data to an array, see working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nu7rZ/103/

angular source link: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/limitTo.js#L3

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't sure how to parse it into the array as well. Nice work, thanks.

Comment: This isn't a real fix for that type of JSON array. It only works for you because you have id's on the outside. I have a JSON array with no id.

Comment: @Xogle I'm sorry this did not resolve your issue, but this issue is in regards to using ng-repeat on a data structure that is not an array. If you have an array then this should not apply to your situation. Please feel free to post your question and link to it here for me to take a look.